# MySQL error code: 3037 Invalid GIS data provided to function mbrcontains

Tags: mysql, asp.net

I have a working database in MySQL. I created backup and restored on server without any error. I queried to find MySQL version

```
 SHOW VARIABLES LIKE "%version%";
```

localhost MySQL version is:

[image]

server MySQL version is:

[image]

localhost is working fine but now in one of my stored procedures there is exception on server:

```
 Error Code: 3037 Invalid GIS data provided to function mbrcontains.
```

I didn't find any help on this exception while I'm not using any geo data.

### Update

I'm using contains in my stored procedure which is creating exception

```
SELECT  Data_Type INTO TargetFieldType FROM information_schema.COLUMNS
    WHERE information_schema.COLUMNS.COLUMN_NAME= TargetFieldName
    AND information_schema.COLUMNS.TABLE_NAME=TableName
    AND information_schema.COLUMNS.TABLE_SCHEMA=dbName; 

    IF (( CONTAINS(@TargetFieldType ,'VARCHAR')= TRUE ) 
    OR (CONTAINS(TargetFieldType,'TEXT')= TRUE ) 
    OR (CONTAINS(TargetFieldType,'LONTTEXT')= TRUE)  
    OR (CONTAINS(TargetFieldType,'CHAR')= TRUE)      ) THEN
    SET TargetFieldValue = '''' + TargetFieldValue +'''';
    END IF ;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After spending hours i found a solution. I have changed contains to Find_In_Set in my sp query

```
SELECT  Data_Type INTO TargetFieldType FROM information_schema.COLUMNS
    WHERE information_schema.COLUMNS.COLUMN_NAME= TargetFieldName
    AND information_schema.COLUMNS.TABLE_NAME=TableName
    AND information_schema.COLUMNS.TABLE_SCHEMA='WMC'; 

    IF (( FIND_IN_SET(@TargetFieldType ,'VARCHAR')= TRUE ) 
    OR (FIND_IN_SET(TargetFieldType,'TEXT')= TRUE ) 
    OR (FIND_IN_SET(TargetFieldType,'LONTTEXT')= TRUE)  
    OR (FIND_IN_SET(TargetFieldType,'CHAR')= TRUE)   ) THEN
    SET TargetFieldValue = '''' + TargetFieldValue +'''';
    END IF ;
```

now its working fine. I dont know the problem yet Except when i run

```
SHOW WARNINGS;
```

it gives Contains is depricated please use mbrcontains but mbrcontains still give the same exception only find_in_set works